# How to remove empty attributes “N/A” in Magento 2?

Tags: attributes, magento2

I am using Magento 2 with Porto theme, I recently updated theme and magento now in product information I am also seeing empty attributes that are unrelated to the current products as N/A . how can I hide them?

I saw people discussing here this in Magento 1. but it doesn't work for 2.0.

please help if you know how to do it. thanks

Comment: This is the quick solution: https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/How-to-remove-empty-attributes-N-A-in-Magento-2/td-p/69329  - but it needs copying the template, there is a better solution via a plugin.

Comment: Get solution from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684391/magento-2-empty-attribute-hide-in-product-details-page/47074866#47074866

Answer (score 0):

`Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

```
   if(strpos($_data['value'],"N/A")===false):?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="col data" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php

            endif;
```