# magento 2 empty attribute hide in product details page

Tags: attributes, hide, magento2

Magento 2 experts, 
Can you please help me, to hide empty/NA attribute in magento 2 products details page ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665119/how-to-remove-empty-attributes-n-a-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is magento core issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9961 , But you can use following solution for now.

Get to attributes.phtml file from :/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

Copy this file and paste in your theme : /app/design/frontend/[YOUR PACKAGE]/[YOUR THEME]/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml.

Search following code:

```
  <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Replace above code by the following code:

```
   <?php
         $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);

         if (!$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) {
            continue;
        }
   ?>

  <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Above solution is working perfectly in Magento 2.2